# Avoid Scanning of WhatsApp audio by Groove or other Music Players

Tags: windows-10-mobile, whatsapp, mediaplayer, groove

Like adding `.nomedia` empty file into the folders that we don't want to be scanned by Music Players or Photo Gallery or Video Players to avoid adding to playlist, is there any option in Windows Phone?

I tried to add `.nomedia` file without any luck....

The Audio files sent in WhatsApp are getting added to Groove Music player and it's very annoying when listening to music. How we can prevent it?

I'm using **Microsoft Lumia 640XL DS with Windows 10 Mobile. OS Build No. 10.0.10586.494**

#### Edit

A comment in a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/4g0fn1/a_way_to_tell_groove_music_which_folders_to_scan/) says like this:

> So, here is a theory: on SD cards I believe Groove scans all files because most people don't respect the Music folder organization scheme when copying music from their other devices. But this may not be true for internal storage.
>
> Is there a way you can set your audiobook app to use internal storage instead to check?

As suggested, it's not possible to store music in internal storage as most of the mobiles come with an internal storage of 8GB where we can usually get 2-3 gb of free space.